# Método isEmpty() dando erro num bloco while

Tags: java

Olá.
Estou desenvolvendo um jogo de tabuleiro e no método abaixo quero verificar se na matriz de inteiros x alguma posição foi setada ou está vasia. Está dando erro na linha: while.

```
public void verificarJogada(int posicao) {  

//iteradores para linha e coluna  

    int i=0;
    int j=0;

//entra no primeiro laço incrementando j. Ou seja, numa linha, verifica todas as colunas por espaços não vazio.  
do {

//o segundo laço (o laço a baixo) incrementa j para as 3 posições referentes a coluna do tabuleiro.  
    while ((this.!x[i][j].isEmpty()) && (j<2)) {
j++;
}
}

// incrementa i que se refere a linha e verifica novamente em cada coluna se tem espaços não vazios.  
for (i=0; i<3; i++);

// fecha o método e a classe.           

    }

}
```

Comment: Formate o código. O erro é `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: a matriz X como você disse, ela é uma matriz de inteiros, certo? Sendo assim, inteiro não tem o método isEmpty. E como é inteiro, você tem que ter valor

Comment: @ramaral  não. Vou postar os erros aqui.

Comment: @Ilario Junior  então eu tenho que declarar uma matriz assim:  public int x[][] = new int[3][3]=0; é isso?

Comment: Ao criar um `int` array ele é preenchido por defeito com o valor `0`. Julgo que o teste que quer fazer seria assim: `(this.x[i][j] != 0) && (j<2)`

Comment: @ramaral  talvez desta forma seja uma solução. Vale tentar.

Answer (score 1):

O seu erro está aqui:

```
 while ((this.!x[i][j].isEmpty()) && (j<2)) {
```

Esse `!` após o `.` não é uma sintaxe válida no java, pois após o `.` o nome de um campo ou método deve seguir-se.

Talvez você quisesse isso:

```
 while ((!this.x[i][j].isEmpty()) && (j<2)) {
```